# How can i get multiple table column name using Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue getting multiple table columns names using eloquent model

Example: I have two table 1)User 2)Posts

1)User Iam able to get all columns names for user

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function getTableColumns() {
        return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
    }

}
```

but what i want combine two model i.e User and post modal and get all column names using eloquent modal

Answer (score 0):

First create **User and Post Modal Relationship** Like that

in **User.php** Modal class

```
public function post() {
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function getTableColumns() {
       return array_merge(
            $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable()), //user modal column
            $this->post()->getTableColumns()   //post modal column
       );
}
```

Second In **Post.php** Modal Class

```
public function scopeGetTableColumns() {
        return $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
 }
```

Third Now Open Your Terminal and run:

```
 php artisan tinker 


(new \App\User)->getTableColumns();
```

> you will get both table columns using relationship..

Other wise Just Pass table name in **User.php** class function do like that

```
public function getTableColumns($tableName = 'posts') {
       return array_merge(
            $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable()), //user modal column
            $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($tableName)   //post modal column
       );
}
```